# Export a CSV file of 365 user licenses and when they were last used

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that generates a csv report of all our 365 users, what licenses are applied to them and when those licenses were last used by the users, below is what I have so far but it does not generate the last used date for the licenses, thank you in advance for any assistance you may be able to provide.

```
# Install the AzureAD module if you haven't already
# Install-Module AzureAD

# Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD

# Create an empty array to store user license information
$report = @()

# Get all Office 365 users
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userLicenses = Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail -ObjectId $user.ObjectId

    # Check if the user has any licenses before including them in the report
    if ($userLicenses.Count -gt 0) {
        $lastUsedLicense = $userLicenses | Sort-Object -Property LastUsed -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

        $licenseInfo = @{
            DisplayName = $user.DisplayName
            UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
            LicenseName = $lastUsedLicense.SkuPartNumber
            LastUsed = $lastUsedLicense.LastUsed
        }

        $report += New-Object PSObject -Property $licenseInfo
    }
}

# Specify the full path including the directory where the CSV report will be saved
$reportPath = "C:\Users\Documents\Office365UserLicenseReport.csv"

# Add the header row to the CSV file
$header = "DisplayName", "UserPrincipalName", "LicenseName", "LastUsed"
$reportWithHeader = $report | Select-Object $header

# Export the report to the specified CSV file
$reportWithHeader | Export-Csv -Path $reportPath -NoTypeInformation

# Disconnect from Azure AD
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

I tried to generate a CSV report of all users in 365, their licenses and the last used date of those licenses but could not generate the last used date.